# InvalidArgumentError for autoencoder with keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm training an autoencoder (with the keras blog code), and I'm getting the fallowing error

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [1,420,748,3] vs. [1,422,750,3]
 [[Node: loss/conv2d_7_loss/sub = Sub[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](conv2d_7/Sigmoid, _arg_conv2d_7_target_0_1)]]
```

In some search people have pointed that is a problem of too much memory consumption on GPU. But I'm loading one image a time and training with

```
m.fit(blured, img, epochs = 1, batch_size = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your variables "blured" (420 x 748 x 3) and "img" (422 x 750 x 3) do not have the same shape. Auto-encoder expects same input and label shapes since it is trained to learn to go from inputs into a bottleneck layer and from there to labels.

Comment: But they have, if I type on the notebook 



    blured.shape == img.shape

I get

    True

Comment: What are the shapes if you print them individually?

Comment: img.shape : (1, 422, 750, 3)





blured.shape : (1, 422, 750, 3)